# Is it possible to do a subquery to return an array for the $nin operator in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data set that looks something like:

```
{"key": "abc", "val": 1, "status": "np"}
{"key": "abc", "val": 2, "status": "p"}
{"key": "def", "val": 3, "status": "np"}
{"key": "ghi", "val": 4, "status": "np"}
{"key": "ghi", "val": 5, "status": "p"}
```

I want a query that returns document(s) that have a status="np" but only where there are other documents with the same key that do not have a status value of "p".  So the document returned from the data set above would be key="def" since "abc" has a value of "np" but "abc" also has a document with a value of "p".  This is also true for key="ghi".  I came up with something close but I don't think the $nin operator supports q distinct query.

```
db.test2.find({$and: [{"status":"np"}, {"key": {$nin:[<distinct value query>]]})
```

If I were to hardcode the value in the $nin array, it would work:

```
db.test2.find({$and: [{"status":"np"}, {"key": {$nin:['abc', 'ghi']}}]})
```

I just need to be able to write a find inside the square brackets.  I could do something like:

```
var res=[];
res = db.test2.distinct("key", {"status": "p"});
db.test2.find({$and: [{"status":"np"}, {"key": {$nin:res}}]});
```

But the problem with this is that in the time between the two queries, another process may update the "status" of a document and then I'd have inconsistent data.

Comment: Maybe you can try using aggregation. 1. Group by key. 2. $elemMatch to filter the status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
db.so.aggregate([
 {$group: {'_id': '$key', 'st': {$push: '$status'}}},
 {$project :{st: 1, '$val':1, '$status':1, 'hasNp':{$in:['np', '$st']}, hasP: {$in:['p', '$st']}}},
 {$match: {hasNp: true, hasP: false}}
]);
```

Comment: Close, but that doesn't retrieve the actual document.

Comment: You just need to add the fields you want to the $project phase